# Spring Data Neo4j Repository.save works incorrectly if it performs update

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I tried to perform following actions via repository (SDN 4.0.0.RC2):

1. I save `entity` with an property with `null` value
2. I save `entity` again (i.e update it), but now property has a value

In this case updating is not performed. Value still is null. Is it a bug?

Comment: Please show your code for both save() calls, including how you ensure that you are updating the same entity.

Comment: Also show your entity. Perhaps best a failing unit-test.